# Variable Insert in MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am fetching some row from mysql table and after fetch it I am inserting it in another database with similar type table. I want little changes in one filed of row and want insert fixed value in it instead of value that I have fetched first.

My current query is like below

```html
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($questions))
$cat=1;
{
    // escape your strings
    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {
        $row[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mobcon, $row[$key]);
    }
    mysqli_query($mobcon, "INSERT INTO `questions` (`option1`, `option2`, `option3`, `option4`, `correctans`, `question_text`, `cat_id`, `sub_cat_id`, `level_id`, `quesimage`) VALUES ('" . $row['option1'] . "', '" . $row['option2'] . "', '" . $row['option3'] . "','" . $row['option4'] . "','" . $row['correctans'] . "','" . $row['question_text'] . "','" . $row['cat_id'] . "','" . $row['sub_cat_id'] . "','" . $row['level_id'] . "','" . $row['quesimage'] . "');");
}
```

Now if I want put **value 1 for $row['cat_id']** what should I change it in my code ? I have tried to use variable for it but its not working. Thanks

Comment: So $row['cat_id']=1; doesn't work for you?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks..its working fine !

Comment: you can use mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions) in case you are familiar with associative arrays